# If statement in a for loop wont work

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is my problem. I am trying to trouble shoot this code by using an alert message to pop up at specific sections of the code. **Every alert is executing except the last one. Any ideas why?** All I have in the HTML page is a button that calls the testing function.

```
var pics= new Array();

function testing() {
  alert("1");
  pics[0] = new Image();
  pics[0].src = "images/pic1.jpg";
  pics[1] = new Image();
  pics[1].src = "images/pic2.jpg";
  pics[2] = new Image();
  pics[2].src = "images/pic3.jpg";
  alert("2");
  for(var i = 0; i< pics.length; i++) {
    if (pics[i]<1) {
      alert("3");
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: You're comparing an image element to a number?

Comment: `pics[i]<1`? what is that testing for.

Comment: when did you expect it o shoot?

Comment: What is that if statement for? Why do you check if an `Image` object is less than 1?

Comment: `if (pics[i]<1)` will never be true in this case. What are you trying to test here exactly?

Comment: To be clear, the `if` statement is working perfectly.

Comment: `if` works perfectly, but you need to give it a valid logical condition. Try `if(true)` if you are doubting that `if` statements actually work.

Comment: or, change it to `if (pics[i])` , this will check if the object is not null.

Comment: What are you trying at `pics[i] < 1` ?

Comment: pics[i]<1 is supposed to test for the length of the array its meant to count  through the array and give me an alert for each of time it counts throuhg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pics[i] is not numeric value, you can not compare this with 1.

Comment: Well, you *can*, it's just never going to give a useful result.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to cover it into comment

Comment: It's not my down vote, and I said nothing about comments. However until you can leave comments (reputation >49), I'd suggest not leaving comments in the answer space, it's a method of attracting down-votes.

Comment: Thanks David. Earlier comment was not for you. I'll take care it in ahead.

Comment: Comment or not, your answer is incorrect. You can compare any value with any other value in JavaScript.

Comment: From next time I'll take care of it.

Comment: So shall I delete this answer?